# 301 Moved Permanently error on route optional parameter laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, routes

I am getting the 2 errors 1 after the other

1- 301 moved permanently
2- 404 not found

Accessing this route from ajax and the route is

```
Route::get('/recipientForm/{name?}', function ($name = 'test') {
    return 'test';
});
```

Comment: Are using https request for a http site? Also, try remove the first slash 'recipientForm/{name?}'

Comment: working on Windows, localhost, wampserver.
Also tried it with your option

Comment: Please explain the reason for down vote!

Answer (score 7):

In my case i was used extra slash "/" in the end of url. when i have remove that is working fine

Comment: Chatgpt couldn't solve this lol , Stackoverflow forever